# When passing an object from a class to another, it's reset to initial values in the receiving class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a GUI using javafx, both Sender and Receiver classes are controllers for fxml files.

I trying to pass a `Ball` object from a class to another, but it's reset to initial values in the receiving class.

This is my Code:

```
    class Sender {
    
     void method{
     Ball ball = new Ball("RED");
     Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
     receiver.setBall(ball);
     }
    
    }
```

---

```
    class Receiver {
    
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    
    public Receiver(){ };
    
    void setBall(Ball senderBall){
    this.ball = senderBall;
    }
    // using a button to check
    void testDisplay(){
    System.out.println("the ball color IS :"+ ball.color);
// it prints out the default color of the Ball, not the color RED that i passer from the class "Sender"
    }
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: This code does not make much sense. In Sender you create a Receiver and give it a ball and then immediately forget the Receiver. Also if both Sender and Receiver a supposed to be controllers, then you should keep in mind that you normally never instantiate these controllers because the FXML loader does that.

Answer (score 1):

Script is great-written, but you forgot to call void method() in your testDisplay() void from class Sender

```
void testDisplay(){    
    Sender send = new Sender();
    send.method();
    System.out.println("the ball color IS :"+ ball);
}
```